# Enity linq query taking too long

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity

I had a query that was running quickly with this, would take about two seconds to run and I made a change and now can't pinppoint what change is making this take 15 seconds to run now. Any ideas what I could have done?

```
     var longReturnListt =
         await (from i in db.Inventory_Vehicles
                join l in db.Inventory_Descriptions on new {inv = i.ID, cli = i.ClientID} equals
                new {inv = l.InventoryID, cli = l.ClientID} into descGroup
                from m in descGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join s in db.Settings_Exports on i.ClientID equals s.ClientID into settingGroup
                from sg in settingGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join sl in db.Settings_Lots on new {client = sg.ClientID, lot = sg.LotID} equals
                new {client = sl.ClientID, lot = sl.ID} into lotsGroup
                from lg in lotsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                //join se in db.Settings_ExportSites on new {client = lg.ClientID, lotId = i.LotID, site = siteId } equals new {client = se.ClientID, lotId = se.LotID, site = se.Site} into exportGroup
                //from eg in exportGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join f in db.Inventory_Features on new {inv = i.ID, cli = i.ClientID} equals
                new {inv = f.InventoryID, cli = f.ClientID} into invFeatGroup
                from ifg in invFeatGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join p in db.Inventory_Photos on i.ID equals p.InventoryID into photo
                from photos in photo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where
                i.ClientID == "999995" && i.Archived != "1" && i.Holding != "1" &&
                i.Status == "A"
                orderby i.ID
                select new { i, m, sg, photoo = photo.ToList(), lg, ifg } into grouped
                group grouped by new { grouped.i.ID, grouped.i.ClientID } into groupedDone

                //group photos by new {photos.InventoryID} into pg
                select new NewType
                {
                  InventoryVehicles = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.i).FirstOrDefault(),
                  InventoryDescriptions = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.m).FirstOrDefault(),
                  SettingsExports = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.sg).FirstOrDefault(),
                  //InventoryPhotos = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.photoo).FirstOrDefault(),
                  SettingsLots = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.lg).FirstOrDefault(),
                  InventoryFeatures = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.ifg).FirstOrDefault(),
                  // SettingsExportSites = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.eg).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToListAsync();
    returnList.AddRange(longReturnListt);
    return returnList;
```

Comment: Stop doing so many joins in SQL, Load all of your entities in seperate queries so that you don't get carstesian production, then join everything in memory

Comment: Have you tried profiling the resulting query to determine if there are indexes you need?  Are all the joins on foriegn keys?  If not then you likely can improve performance with some indexes.

Comment: @johnny5 I went ahead and created the separate queries for each one but I'm unsure how I'd go about joining the queries together, do you have a small example by chance?

Comment: Basically, this whole architecture should be redone.  Your focus on coding should be to make it readable so it can be maintained easy, you don't want to have to understand, 1 Million things to find out that you just want a list of Active, Vechicles with client id X. You should post this on StackOverFlow Code review for better insight

Comment: I don't feel like taking the time to understand such a long query, you should really get this code reviewed.  But if you just want it to work and you don't care then, just use the loaded data, list(hopefully you filtered them first so you dont load any extra) and then  put them inside of the joins instead,

Comment: @johnny5 I went ahead and posted on StackOverFlow's code review, thank you.  I know I desperately need to go through that as I wasn't in an environment where I've gotten it before.  I really appreciate the help and I'm going to go ahead and clean this up